# Opencv image inpainting failed

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to inpaint some affine warped images in an iOS project.

First I create a `frame_mask`:

```
frame_mask.create(image_size, CV_8U);
frame_mask.setTo(255);
```

Second I apply the same affine transformation to the `frame_mask`:

```
cv::warpAffine(frame_mask, transformed_mask, T, image_size, cv::INTER_CUBIC);
```

Finally, I do the inpainting:

```
cv::inpaint(frame, transformed_mask, inpainted_frame, 5, CV_INPAINT_TELEA);
```

But the result did not match my expectations.

The output is either black or image shown below.
[image: output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was solved by accident.
I generated a wrong mask.

Adding the following code could help:

```
cv::bitwise_not(stabilized_mask, stabilized_mask);
```